# Differential equation : $\frac{dy}{dx} -\frac{y}{x}=2x^2, x > 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem :

Solve the differential equation :

$$\frac{dy}{dx} -\frac{y}{x}=2x^2, \quad x > 0$$

Solution :

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)y =2x^2 \tag i$$

It  is linear differential equation of the form :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+Py =Q$$ where $$P = -\frac{1}{x}\text{ and }Q =2x^2$$

Now Integrating factor (I.F.) : $=e^{\int P \, dx} = e^{\int \frac{-1}{x}} = \frac{1}{x}$.

Multiply both sides of $(\mathrm{i})$ by I.F.   we get :

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{x^2}y=2x$$

Now integrating both sides w.r.t. x we get :

$$y\cdot \frac{1}{x} =\int 2x \, dx +C$$

Now my question is what happened to $\dfrac{1}{x^2}y$ after introducing integrating factor please guide on this point will be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the product rule. Note that $(y\frac{1}{x})'=y'\frac{1}{x}-y\frac{1}{x^2}$